# Problemas com Thread (Koltin)

Tags: android, thread, kotlin

Estou numa situação em que estou construindo um APP para android para ficar consultando as variações de cotação do Bitcoin no site Mercado Bitcoin.

O APP já está funcionando, a última coisa que pretendo implementar é a consulta automática em intervalos de tempo.

O método startAll() dispara a consulta, joga os dados atuais na tela e guarda alguns dados no banco de dados.

Para isso estou usando uma Thread, mas quando chamo o método startAll() dentro da Thread o APP fecha. Não estou entendendo o por quê, pois esse mesmo esquema consigo reproduzir no IntelliJ com sucesso.

Até tentei colocar a chamada do método dentro de um try/catch para visualizar o possível erro, mas sem sucesso.

OBS: coloquei esta classe dentro do onCreate

Há outra maneira mais adequada de fazer isto?

Segue o código:

```
class thread() : Thread() {

        override fun run() {

            var count = 0
            while (count < 28000) {
                try{
                    startAll()
                }catch (ex:Exception){
                    errorMessage(ex.message.toString())
                }

                count++
                Thread.sleep(30000)

            }
        }
    }

    val t = thread()
    t.start()
```

Aparece o seguinte erro no LOG

```
07-18 08:47:31.234 1918-1956/com.example.tjsid.cry E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-172
Process: com.example.tjsid.cry, PID: 1918
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
    at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:345)
    at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:101)
    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:259)
    at com.example.tjsid.cry.MainActivity.errorMessage(MainActivity.kt:103)
    at com.example.tjsid.cry.MainActivity$onCreate$thread.run(MainActivity.kt:70)
07-18 08:47:31.238 579-987/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.tjsid.cry/.MainActivity
07-18 08:47:31.296 592-592/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 592: eglCreateSyncKHR(1215): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
07-18 08:47:31.386 1918-1934/com.example.tjsid.cry E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xdf9b44d0
```

Implementação do startAll()

```
fun startAll() {
    val basicUrl = "https://www.mercadobitcoin.net/api/"
    val urlBit = "BTC/ticker/"
    val urlLit = "LTC/ticker/"
    val urlBCash = "BCH/ticker/"
    val listViewBit = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listaBit)
    val listViewLit = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listaLit)
    val listViewBCash = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listaBCash)
    val listViewDates = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listaDate)
    get(basicUrl + urlBit)
    get(basicUrl + urlLit)
    get(basicUrl + urlBCash)
    down_bar.text = "Última atualização " + date.getAllHour()
    listViewBit.adapter = MyCustomAdapter(this, getLastPrice(urlBit, this), "bitcoin")
    listViewLit.adapter = MyCustomAdapter(this, getLastPrice(urlLit, this), "litcoin")
    listViewBCash.adapter = MyCustomAdapter(this, getLastPrice(urlBCash, this), "bcash")
    listViewDates.adapter = MyCustomAdapter(this, getLastDate(this), "date")
}
```

Comment: Veja se no logcat aparece algum erro. Adicione também na pergunta a implementação do método `startAll` para facilitar.

Comment: Alterei a postagem conforme sugeriu para ajudar a encontrar o problema. Esse método startAll() é chamado assim que o APP é iniciado e também está atrelado ao evento de clique de botão para atualizar manualmente e desse jeito funciona, mas quero que o APP faça essa atualização automaticamente enquanto estiver sendo executado em intervalos de 30 segundos, daí encontrei esse problema...

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você está tentando alterar a view a partir de outra thread que não é a main.

Execute o código altera a view em um bloco `runOnUiThread`:

```
runOnUiThread {
    down_bar.text = "Última atualização " + date.getAllHour()
    listViewBit.adapter = MyCustomAdapter(this, getLastPrice(urlBit, this), "bitcoin")
    listViewLit.adapter = MyCustomAdapter(this, getLastPrice(urlLit, this), "litcoin")
    listViewBCash.adapter = MyCustomAdapter(this, getLastPrice(urlBCash, this), "bcash")
    listViewDates.adapter = MyCustomAdapter(this, getLastDate(this), "date")
}
```

Parece que seu método `errorMessage` mostra um `Toast`, então ele precisaria desse tratamento tbm:

```
runOnUiThread {
    errorMessage(ex.message.toString())
}
```